# Why is this preg_match returning empty?

Tags: php, preg-match

I’m trying to get the ID from this URL but it keeps coming back empty. Here is my code:

This is what the URLs look like on the website i'm looking on:

```
<b><a href="index.php?page=news&amp;id=32662f87eb22a90d81b2362c6ff458a57643eff1"
```

This is my PHP

```
$pattern = "#<b><a href=\"index.php?page=news&amp;id=(.*?)\"#i";
preg_match_all($pattern,$openSite,$match);
```

Comment: are you sure that the input is correct? I think the input has more atributes than your RegEx has.

Comment: $openSite is opening a website with a list of URLs like the in my regex, I'm trying to get all the IDs.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss The URLs on the site are like: <b><a href="index.php?page=news&amp;id=32662f87eb22a90d81b2362c6ff458a57643eff1"

Comment: are you sure? The RegEx dont work if the tag is `<a class="...." href="index.php?..."` for example

Comment: Try to use `preg_match_all("/<a([^href=")+)href="([^"]+)"/Uis", $openSite, $matches);` and print it out: `print_r($matches);`

Answer (score 1):

**`?`** and **`.`** are special characters. You need to add a **`\`** before them.

```
$pattern = "#<b><a href=\"index\.php\?page=news&amp;id=(.*?)\"#i";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = "#\<b\>\s*\<a\s+href\=\"index\.php\?page\=news\&amp\;id\=([^\"\&]*)#i";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simpler pattern: `/id=(.*)$/`

```
<?php

$openSite = '<b><a href="index.php?page=news&amp;id=32662f87eb22a90d81b2362c6ff458a57643eff1"';
$pattern = "/id=(.*)$/";
preg_match_all($pattern,$openSite,$match);
print_r($match[1])

?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 32662f87eb22a90d81b2362c6ff458a57643eff1"
)
```